# Get Viewholder of newly added item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I want to give the user a hint that they can use swipe to delete on a certain item, so I'm trying to implement a partial swipe on a new item.  I will use ItemTouchHelper.startswipe for this however I require the items view holder.

My question is, when I add an item to my RV and call notifyItemInserted(), how do I get the viewholder of the newly added item?  I have tried `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos)`  which returns null each time.  If anyone has any info I'd appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

I did once something like this. While i setup the swipes using `ItemTouchHelper` I achieved the animations with simple animations. Here's how I did it. The animation:

```
private void setupAnimation() {
    swipeAnimation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            int direction = animationRepeatTime < 2 ? 1 : -1;
            if (animatingView != null) {
                animatingView.setTranslationX(direction * interpolatedTime * Utils.convertDpToPixel(100, context));
            } else {
                swipeAnimation.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    swipeAnimation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    swipeAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    swipeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3);
    swipeAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            animationRepeatTime++;
        }
    });
    swipeAnimation.setStartOffset(600);
    swipeAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
    swipeAnimation.setDuration(500);
}
```

In onBindViewHolder to stop the animation when item is touched:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ActivityStreamViewHolder) {
        bindActivityHolder((ActivityStreamViewHolder) holder, position);
        if (position == 1 && shouldAnimate) {
            startAnimation(holder.itemView);
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (swipeAnimation != null && swipeAnimation.hasStarted() && !swipeAnimation.hasEnded()) {
                         shouldAnimate = false;
                        swipeAnimation.cancel();
                        animatingView.clearAnimation();
                        animatingView.setTranslationX(0);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

For starting the animation:

```
public void startAnimation(View view) {
    animatingView = view;
    if (shouldAnimate && getItemCount() > 1 && animatingView.getAnimation() == null) {
        animatingView.startAnimation(swipeAnimation);
        shouldAnimate = false;
    }
}
```

You can modify it to match your case.